# Nodejs, Sinon: How to test some functions are called upon an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, eventemitter

Say I have an object in my code, let's say a **User**.

User is an eventEmitter so in many places in the code I do like:

```
User.on('register', notifyFriends);
User.on('register', sendWelcomeEmail);
```

This lines are in different files in principal.

I want to make sure that the relevant functions are called in my test so I do something like this:

```
describe('User Events', () => {
  before(() => {
    sinon.stub(userListeners, 'notifyFriends').callsFake(async () => {});
  });
  after(() => {
    userListeners.notifyFriends.restore();
  });

  describe('register', () => {
    it('should trigger the "notifyFriends" handler once user is registered', () => {

      UserModel.emit('register');
      expect(userListeners.notifyFriends).to.be.calledOnce();

    });
  });
});
```

Problem is the the function is run after the expect statement so the test fails obviously.

An easy way to solve it is to run the expect inside a Timeout block and hope that the function is called within the given time.

But I want to know if there is a better, more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was different.

The code that registers to the handlers was executed before the stub was made. (So the function wasn't a spy yet)

So make sure to run the stub, only after run the rest of the code in the application that registers to the evetns.